# How to add contacts from your application and save it in the addressbook?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, contacts, addressbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you add contacts to the iPhone Address book with monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821661/how-do-you-add-contacts-to-the-iphone-address-book-with-monotouch)

I have searched, and havnt find any tutorials about how to save contacts from your application  in your addressbook.

If you have some contacts in your application you may want to save them in your phones contact list so you have all the contacts at the same place.

Anything that can help is good, tutorials or whatever.

Comment: this has been discussed before - see above question

Answer (score 1):

A useful starting point and reference is the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html).  In particular you'll want to invoke:

> **ABAddressBookAddRecord**
>   Adds a record to an address book.
>
> ```
> bool ABAddressBookAddRecord (  
>     ABAddressBookRef addressBook,  
>     ABRecordRef record,  
>     CFErrorRef *error  
> );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - *addressBook*
>     The address book to which record is added.
> - *record*
>     The record to add to addressBook.
> - *error*
>     On error, contains error information. See “Address Book Errors.”
>
> **Return Value**
>   *true* when successful, *false* otherwise.
>
> **Availability**
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>   ABAddressBook.h