# Open gallery in simulator on image tap

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to open the gallery in iPhone simulator upon button click.
I am using Xamarin forms - xaml to create pages and image views.

**What I have implemented so far :** 
I have a GalleryService specific to iOS that implements IGalleryService that has a method selectImage. The selectImage creates a UIImagePickerController _imagePicker.

In iOS specific apps, I would just do

```
 NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(_imagePicker, true);
```

But how to do something similar using Navigation in xamarin forms?

PS: I have created view in .xaml file and move across pages in xaml.cs file like

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(page)
```

Here, the page must basically contain the _imagePicker view, right? How to do that?
Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms actually utilises a single NavigationController on iOS to host all the different pages. All of the Xamarin Content Pages navigation happens internally in XF, inside the single main NavigationController.

You cannot mix other native view controllers inside the NavigationPage stack. But you can use all the native code you normally would and just treat the one NavigationController that forms uses as a single "screen".

Inside the iOS native project, you can use

```
var topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
while (topController.PresentedViewController != null) {
    topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
}
topController.PresentViewController (_imagePicker, true, null);
```

to access the XF's view controller, find the top one and use that like you would in a "native" ios app to present the modal view.

Note that this RootViewController will be null until "LoadApplication" finishes, so make sure any calls are made after that, which should always be the case if you are triggering this action from the running app and not immediately on startup.

If using PCL's, you would need some form of a DependencyService to trigger this call from your shared code, and you might need a bit more logic in the native app to get the result back into the shared code. You would also need to reimplement this on any other platforms you might be targeting with your app (such as Android or UWP).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Let me try that and get back. :)

Comment: I am getting this Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: looks like that didn't give us the reference to the actual UINavigationController that you should call present on. Take a look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912739/how-to-show-ios-add-contact-screen-from-xamarin-forms see if that helps you.

Comment: Tried that accepted answer. But there seems to be only one view controller and that too of type : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.

Comment: Hey, found this link working for me. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28091/uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Awesome find, I have updated the answer with the working code sample for anyone who finds it in the future.